# GitHub auth and ssh keys on Debian: I've tried everything I could find

Tags: debian, ssh, authentication, ssh-agent, github

GitHub auth continues to fail for me despite my taking all the advice I could find on the Internet.

Here are the permissions on my .ssh directory and keys. I have changed the private key permissions to 600, the public keys to 644, and the directory to 700.

```
    drwx------  2 user user 4096 Jan 15 19:20 .
    drwxr-xr-x 37 user user 4096 Jan 15 19:16 ..
    -rw-------  1 user user  484 Dec 11 05:55 id_ed25519
    -rw-r--r--  1 user user  114 Dec 11 05:55 id_ed25519.pub
    -rw-------  1 user user 1876 Aug 19 17:52 id_rsa
    -rw-r--r--  1 user user  396 Aug 19 17:52 id_rsa.pub
    -rw-------  1 user user 1768 Jan  2 10:26 known_hosts
```

ssh-agent knows about the ed25519 key.

```
     user@PureOS:~$ ssh-add -l
     256 SHA256:/string user@domain.com (ED25519)
```

**I even restarted my laptop** after changing permissions on the .ssh directory and files.

And ... STILL, the relevant result from `ssh -Tv git@github.com`:

```
    debug1: Server accepts key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 
    SHA256:/string agent
    sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
```

Answer (score 0):

Backup the ssh files under `~/.ssh`

```
mkdir ~/ssh-bak
mv ~/.ssh/* ~/ssh-bak
```

Generate a new ssh key (see [Generating a new SSH key)](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#generating-a-new-ssh-key):

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C your@mail.here
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

copy the key:

```
xclip -selection clipboard < ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
```

Add it to your github account https://github.com/settings/keys (see [adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) )

Test it:

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

You should recive:

```
Hi $USER! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```